# Eclipse content-assit not working in primefaces var datatable

Tags: eclipse, primefaces, eclipse-wtp, content-assist

With Eclipse Kepler SR1 the content-assist not working with a declared var in a  datatable primefaces :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{testManagedBean.listAllDomaines()}" var="pRow" >
  <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{pRow.}" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The `#{pRow.}` + CTRL space show enithing.

While with a classic datatable it's ok :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{testManagedBean.lstdDomaines}" var="stdRow">
  <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{stdRow.iddom}" />
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Any ideas ?

Regards,

Stef

Answer (score 0):

Open your Eclipse and in menu bar choose:

`Window > Preferences >`

`General > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP (select)`

- Click in **"Add..."** button
- Insert: ***.xhtml**
- Press **"OK"** button
- Now your problem was resolved